On average, how long does it take to become competent at performing a go-around?
Some pilots spend one to two hours practicing go-arounds. That seems a bit long. And frequently there will be 2-4 (or more) pilots practicing go-arounds at the same time. The lowest altitude they usually go over the runway is 1000-1400 feet.

Huh?  At most airports the highest you would fly in the pattern is 1000'. Most traffic patterns are set at 800 to 1000 feet AGL. And the purpose is to practice approach and landing, thus actually touching down before going around. Although if you are practicing instrument approaches, you may go around at the missed approach point which is normally about 200' AGL and just short of the runway. BTW, pilots practice takeoffs and landings as that's where small errors can get you in the most trouble.

There's becoming competent, (training) and staying competent, (practice) and both need to happen.  Also, as Gerry mentioned, it is most likely instrument approach training/practice you are noticing from the way you described it.

I personally like to teach students go-around technique on the first flight and have them doing it on every flight thereafter, prior to teaching them landing techniques. Making use of E.L. Thorndike’s Law of Primacy, it’s a good way to ingrain the idea that the student can always go around but landing the airplane is an option.
So to answer your question once or twice on every flight is fine for practice.
Now it’s possible that a pilot may, in addition to go-around techniques, may also be working on workflows and/or memory items during this process, which may require multiple attempts.  I recommend no more than four such attempts, followed by terminating the exercise and landing to digest their perceptions and insights of the experience.
As for minimum altitudes, typically when practicing a low approach, you will not fly lower than 500 ft AGL during the approach and/or to satisfy the requirements of §91.119(a).  ATC at tower controlled airports may restrict you to higher minimums at their discretion.
